# FloatingActionButton placement Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make floating button, but i need help with the placement hierarchy. As if I leave it in a Column it place a white column and inside of it there is the button. I think it must be placed in Row, but tried to do it unsuccessfully.

Thank you in advance!

```
   body: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 12),
                  Expanded(
                    child: HomeView(),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xff03dac6),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Respond to button press
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  )
                ],
              ),
        );
```

What I'm getting. So, I would like to Get rid off that white column so the button would only exist.
[Picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AxjV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
adding   `floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,` in Scaffold will shows in center

[image: Screenshot]

**Code**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
          void _incrementCounter() {}
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(widget.title),
              ),
              body: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('row $index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                tooltip: 'Increment',
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: It worked @Assassin you killed it, thank you

Comment: @Chorche

Answer (score 1):

An image like example it would be fine.

I don't know if you mean this, but I'll leave you an example

**EDITED**

Sorry for the delay, here is the example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (_, __) {
            return Divider();
          },
          itemBuilder: (_, i) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Hola Mundo $i'),
            );
          }, itemCount: 100,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @matr0s i have added picture for you

Comment: Do you want to do something like this?

https://ibb.co/ZLZkmCJ

Comment: exactly @fernando-luis-martínez

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my friend.

I edited the answer, enjoy the example.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try Positioned() widget?
Not clear what result do you want to get.

Comment: i have added picture for you